# How to populate the RobotFramework Test Documentation in XRay JIRA Test Description

Tags: jira-xray

I have written a RobotFramework listener to auto-import the test execution into JIRA XRay. I can see that the tags of the test case is showing up as Label but the documentation of the test is not showing up as Description.

I am using the below as the API endpoint to do the robotframeowrk test result import. Is it possible to do so? If not, can this be added in the future? i've looked at the multipart solution, but it is not useful as one has to create the json for each test where the test documentation is expected to be different. Please advise.

```
self.xray_api_endpoint = "{}/rest/raven/1.0/import/execution/robot".format(self.xray_host)
```

[image: What I am looking for]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently this is not yet possible.
There is a [feature request in the backlog](https://jira.getxray.app/browse/XRAY-7949), at least for Xray server/datacenter; please watch it and vote on it, so the team can keep track of your interest.
If you're using Xray on Jira Cloud, then please reach out [Xray support team](https://jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2) so they can provide feedback based on the PO and eventually create the feature request.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep a watch on https://jira.getxray.app/browse/XRAY-7949.

Comment: Can I kindly ask you to mark the answer as correct? thanks in advance :)